# How to unselect all selected rating star when click on the same star in html?

Tags: javascript, html, rating-system

I have developed a web page for the star ratings. I need to unselect the stars if the user clicks twice on the same star, how to unselect all the star rating values? that means if the user clicks on 3 stars for the rating and again click on the 3rd star how to disappear all the rating stars value?

**This is what I tried**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is Home page</h1>
    <p>This is a testing page for rating.</p>
    <div>
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="1" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="2" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="3" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="4" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate()" class="star" id="5" src="./img/star.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="6" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="7" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="8" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="9" src="./img/star.png" />
        <img onClick="rate1()" class="star" id="10" src="./img/star.png" />
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
<script>
    function rate() {
        const { id } = event.target;
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
            } else {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
            }
        }
    }

    function rate1() {
        const { id } = event.target;
        var i;
        for (i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/fillstar.png");
            } else {
                document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add class to every rated star to indicate if it is filled or not (e.g, add class name `filled` to every rated star). Then, on every click check if the element of `event.target` contains the class `filled`. If so, call your functions and in addition, remove all `filled` classes (unrate). If not, add `filled` class to every relevant star (rate).

To dynamically toggle (add or remove) a class to an element, you can use `element.classList.toggle("className")`.

- see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
- code example (similar to yours): https://stackblitz.com/edit/star-rating-demo?file=index.html

Comment: Could you please add some code Sample into my code above? I didn't get the idea clearly.

Comment: I guess you want something like this: https://star-rating-demo.stackblitz.io. see code link in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

first get all the elements inside an array so you can have access to them

`var stars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".star"));`

make a function to uncheck all the stars in your array

```
function uncheckAllStars(){
    starts.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.setAttribute("src", "./img/star.png");
    })
}
```

and now add `ondblclick` to your star elements which trigger when you double click on the element

`<img onClick="rate1()" ondblclick="uncheckAllStars()" class="star" id="9" src="./img/star.png" />`

now when you double click on a star all of the other stars will be unfilled(their source of image change in this case)
this is the idea you can tweak it till it fit your needs

Comment: When double click on page it geting zooming